# Update database with jquery event mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, database, sql-update, mouseleave

Is it possible to update your database with a jquery event as mouseleave? if you get the id and update top and left cordinates?

I'm creating some notes and you kan move them around and i want to get the cordinates from top and left updated to the database on mouseleave ? i'm open-minded so if you have a better suggestion please share!

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".note_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $top = $this.offset().top;
  var $left = $this.offset().left;

  alert("id:" + this.id + " top:" + $top + " left" + $left);

  });
  });
  </script>
```

i know that the code is not near what i'm hoping to achieve, but its was so i could se if i cacth the id, top and left and i did, but how du i get i to my db ? - if it is possible with mouseleave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to go with ajax and php:

```
$(".note_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    var $top = $this.offset().top;
    var $left = $this.offset().left;

   $.post('/save_coordinates.php', {'id': $id,'top': $top, 'left': $left});

});
```

Your save_coordinates.php:

```
$top = $_REQUEST['top'];
$left = $_REQUEST['left'];
$id= $_REQUEST['id'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coordinates(id, top, left) VALUES (".$id." " .$top.", ".$left.")")
```

**Reference**

[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: still having some trouble but thanks. i try ti update it $mysqli->query("UPDATE $table SET top = '$top', left = '$left' WHERE id='$id'");  but no luck yet

Comment: it's deffiently the  save_coordinates.php i have to find the issue, because i can se that the post sents the values in console in inspect element                                                                                                           <?php
$top = $_REQUEST["top"];
$left = $_REQUEST["left"];
$id= $_REQUEST["id"];
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $database);
$mysqli->query("UPDATE $table SET top = '$top', left = '$left' WHERE id='$id'");
?>

Comment: have you checked if the variables have the right values and if the connection to the databased is correct ?

Comment: solved it i had made a mistake in my query so thank you very much for your time!!                                                                                                              if (!mysql_query("UPDATE `$database`.`$table` SET `left` = '$left', `top` = '$top', `position` = 'absolute' WHERE `$table`.`id` =$id"))

Answer (score 0):

This code is running in the client's browser. What you need to do is use an ajax request to send a message to your web server that something happened. JQuery has an ajax() function (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that you can use to do this. You will need a page on the server that you will send the request to and it will need to handle the arguments passed to it (id, top, and left?), and then insert this information into the database. This may cause a lot of queries to your web server and database.